# Reordering same characters such that the characters are at least distance d from each other

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Please help me in writing a python code for below problem:

> Given a string of lowercase characters, reorder them such that the
>   same characters are at least distance d from each other.
>
> **Input:** `{ a, b, b }, distance = 2`
>
> **Output:** `{ b, a, b }`

Comment: Please help us in helping you, by showing us your code and explain what difficulties you are having.

Comment: @Akash Deep added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried an approach for solving this problem. It tries to create a list of characters and fill it with characters from the original string, in the order of their frequency. For example, for a string 'babac' with given distance 2, it fills in the order:

```
most common:  ('b', 3)  # character b with frequency 3
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
updated o:  ['b', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['b', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
updated o:  ['b', '-', 'b', '-', '-', '-']
['b', '-', 'b', '-', '-', '-']
updated o:  ['b', '-', 'b', '-', 'b', '-']
most common:  ('c', 2)
['b', '-', 'b', '-', 'b', '-']
updated o:  ['b', 'c', 'b', '-', 'b', '-']
['b', 'c', 'b', '-', 'b', '-']
updated o:  ['b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', '-']
most common:  ('a', 1)
['b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', '-']
updated o:  ['b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

to give final string bcbcba.

I have pasted the code below. It contains many comments about what each line does and why. Try running it. If you want to get detailed output to know how the list above gets filled, then uncomment the lines that contain `print` statements.

Here is the code, hope its useful:

```
import collections
import math

def printMyString():
  # get inputs
  myStr = raw_input("enter string: ")
  dist = int(raw_input("enter dist: "))

  #create a dict, where each key is a character from myStr and corresponding value is its frequency
  counter = collections.Counter(list(myStr))

  # create an empty list where we will fill our characters to get final string
  o = ['-']*len(myStr)

  # get the most common character
  most_common_char_freq = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]

  # sep is the maximum distance at which repeated instances of the most frequent character m can be located from each other in the final string.
  sep = int(math.ceil(len(myStr)*1.0/most_common_char_freq))

  # if sep is less than given distance, then it is not possible to have such a string.

  if(sep < dist):
    print "such a string is not possible"
    return
  #print "sep", sep


  j = 0 # this marks index at which we can write into the list

  # while we still have characters left, we will continue to fill our output list o 
  while len(counter) > 0:
   current_most_common_char = counter.most_common(1)[0][0]       # get the most common character left in counter        
   current_most_common_char_freq = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]   

   #print "most common: ", current_most_common_char
   while o[j] != '-':  # Go to the next position in the output list where a character is yet to be written.
     j += 1  
     if(j == len(o)):  # We are out of places to write, this is bad!
      # print "breaking, o = ", o
      return

   for i in range(current_most_common_char_freq): # For multiple occurences of the current most freq char, we write them one after the other, a distance of 'sep' apart
    #print o
    if (j+i*sep) >= len(o): # If we have to go beyond the length of the output list/string to write a character, then such a string is not possible
      #print "not possible, o, char is ", o, current_most_common_char
      print "such a string is not possible"
      return
    o[j+i*sep] = current_most_common_char # Write to the output list
    #print "updated o: ", o

   del counter[current_most_common_char] # remove the most common character. lets move on to next one in the loop.
   j += 1 # update before moving on

  print ''.join(o) # merge the characters in the output list to get final string

printMyString()
```